# PHP Code to Process Faster

Tags: php, mysql

I have a running PHP program which handles supplies inventory.

I want this code to process faster to update supplies' balances when opening the page.

SUPPLIES contains the inventory of supplies and their balances.

TRANSACTIONS contains the transactions of receive, return and issued.

The program below retrieves tables' SUPPLIES and TRANSACTIONS and computes the balances from all TRANSACTIONS which updates the MYSQL table of SUPPLIES.

```
<?php
//Update supplies balance starts here
$supplies = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM supplies ORDER BY id DESC");
foreach($supplies->results() as $supply) {
    $balance = 0;
    $transactions = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY id ASC");
    foreach($transactions->results() as $transaction) {
        if($transaction->code === $supply->id){
            if($transaction->transaction_type === "1"){
                $balance = $balance + $transaction->quantity; 
            } else if($transaction->transaction_type === "2"){
                $balance = $balance - $transaction->quantity; 
            } else if($transaction->transaction_type === "3"){
                $balance = $balance + $transaction->quantity; 
            }
        }
    }
    $supplied = new Supply();
    $supplied->find($supply->id);
    try {
        $supplied->update(array(
            'balance' => $balance,
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
//Update supplies balance ends here
?>
```

Comment: Please indent the code properly so it's easier to read. And then think what happens when you have so many loops inside each other and why you need them. Why don't you select from the database based on the conditions rather than looping in PHP code?

Comment: You are selecting the entire `transactions` table once for every single entry in the `supplies` table. Your biggest speed improvement would be to set `$transactions` outside of your `$supplies->results()` loop.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen I know how to select from the database based on the conditions. My problem here is how to regularly update the SUPPLIES table using the date in the TRANSACTIONS table whenever a user opens the page. :(

Comment: Why not JOIN the 2 tables?

Comment: As mentioned, your problem is the queries. Add a condition to run it properly. That will make a huge difference. Meaning at the moment if you had 1000 supplies and 1000 transactions you'd be running 1000000 loops and 2000 queries. With the condition you'd run 1000 loops and 2000 queries returning a lot less data.

Comment: Why are you using this page to update your `supplies` table? Surely the process that adds a transaction to the `transactions` table should [trigger the appropriate change in the `supplies` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: @Phylogenesis I need to retrieve all the `$supply->id` of each **supplies** so I could update each. If I were to set the `$transactions` outside of the `$supplies->results()` then it would be impossible to retrieve each `$supply->id`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis  - I'll try what you're suggesting. I'm getting the picture now. I'll get back to you as soon as I get this one.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Did what you suggested and it's turning out great. But I have a new problem now but is somehow related to this post. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what @Phylogenesis had suggested to include updating `$balance`, straight to the database of `$supplies` based on '$transactions'.

To avoid delays on the client side to update all `$balance` of `$supplies', I used cron jobs to run scripts based on desired schedule.

Installed cronjob for Centos 7 by following steps from this link:

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/automate-system-tasks-using-cron-on-centos-7/

To check if cron's installed, type this: `systemctl status crond.service`

Then used `https://crontab.guru/` to generate expressions to schedule automatically running of PHP scripts.

If still confused on how it works, check out this link for examples:

`https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/`

To install or create or edit your own cron jobs:

1. Type `crontab -e` then ENTER
2. Press `i`, then start typing your expression
3. Type `:wq!` then ENTER to save your cron job.
4. Type `crontab -l` to check for running cron jobs.

That's it! Hope this would help others!

Answer (score 1):

As said @Phylogenesis change in Transaction should trigger update of Supplies.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE transactions SET quantity = ..., code = ..., ....;
UPDATE supplies SET balance = balance +/- ....;
COMMIT;
```

So you do not need to update supplies every time the page was opened, and do not need to recompute entire table. It is important to do this in one transaction. Ideally it should be placed in database in transaction table feature TRIGGER ON UPDATE if possible.

If you can't, try to compute updated value of supplies on database side, example:

```
UPDATE supplies s
    SET balance = 
        (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM transactions t WHERE t.code = s.id AND transaction_type IN (1, 3)) - 
        (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM transactions t WHERE t.code = s.id AND transaction_type = 2);
```

It is still slower but much faster then PHP.

**EDITED:** I update the query example to meet question.

Comment: Dunno how to code this: `UPDATE supplies s SET balance = (SELECT SUM(...) FROM transactions t WHERE t.code = s.id);`

Comment: I edited query to give the same results as question code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. Really appreciated it very much. But I don't know yet how to run codes on database side. My program runs locally on a localhost. Whatever codes I put in is accessed directly by both user and admin.

Comment: I've successfully did what @Phylogenesis had suggested. Whenever there is an update on the transactions. The balance is then immediately updated. But I have a new problem related to this.

Comment: My program creates a table of supplies with its beginning balances, followed by transactions and then ending balances based on the selected period (e.g. July 1, 2017 to July 31, 2017). Even when the user enters the period, June 1, 2017 to June 30, 2017, it can still generate the table just by computing the `$transactions` data from a specified period. But the problem is it's taking too long to produce the table and I'm always facing an error when creating a PDF file of the table.